# How to set an expiration date in java

Tags: java, date

I am trying to write some code to correctly set an expiration date given a certain date.

For instance this is what i have.

```
    Date lastSignupDate = m.getLastSignupDate();
    long expirationDate = 0;
    long milliseconds_in_half_year = 15778463000L;
    expirationDate = lastSignupDate.getTime() + milliseconds_in_half_year; 
    Date newDate = new Date(expirationDate);
```

However, say if i the sign up date is on 5/7/2011 the expiration date output i get is on 11/6/2011 which is not exactly half of a year from the given date.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the Calendar class - the add method will do this kind of thing perfectly.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

```
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);

            java.util.Date expirationDate = cal.getTime();

    System.err.println(expirationDate);
```

Comment: thank you im guna try this.  i cant also convert a calender object to a date object correct? something like this should work: Date t = new Date(cal.getTime().getTime());

Comment: Yes you can.  When you get a Calendar instance back from Calendar.getInstance() that's set to now.  I thought your Date might be coming from somewhere else though.  The call in my code, cal.getTime(), returns a Date object which represents 6 months in the future - so yes you can convert.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple suggestion using joda-time:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(lastSignupDate);
dt = dt.plusDays(DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_DAY * 365 / 2);
// you can also use dt.plusDays(364 / 2);
```

You can also use a `Calendar`:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(lastSignupDate);
c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, MILLIS_PER_DAY * 365 / 2);
// or c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 364 / 2);
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.MAY , 7 )
    .plusMonths( 6 )
    .toString()
```

> 2011-11-07

## java.time

You are using date-time values, so you must account for issues such as time zones, anomalies, and leap year. But you only want a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone, so much easier if you use a date-only class rather than a date-with-time class.

The modern approach uses java.time rather than the troublesome legacy date-time classes.

> if i the sign up date is on 5/7/2011 the expiration date output i get is on 11/6/2011 which is not exactly half of a year from the given date

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.MAY , 7 ) ;
```

You can do math with the java.time classes. Look for `plus…` and `minus…` methods.

```
LocalDate sixMonthsLater = ld.plusMonths( 6 ) ;
```

Or pass the amount of time.

```
Period p = Period.ofMonths( 6 ) ;
LocalDate sixMonthsLater = ld.plus( p ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wNI2z8).

> 2011-05-07
>
> 2011-11-07

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need an expiration-date, which is accurate to the millisecond?

I would implement it as 6 Months from x.

```
Jan. 1 => Jul 1
Sep. 28=> Feb 28
Sep. 29=> Feb 28
Sep. 30=> Feb 28
Oct. 1=>  Mar 1
```

Maybe you like to be generous, and say 'Mar 1' for 'Sep 29 and 30' too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using Date with TimeUnit that's a little more readable:

```
long year = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(365, TimeUnit.DAYS);
Date expiry = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + year);
System.out.println(expiry);
```

Shame it doesn't have year and day, look at GregorianCalendar or Jodatime for a better API.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(new Date().getTime());
// 10 minutes expiration time
calendar.add(calendar.MINUTE, 10);
// prints 10 minutes ahead time  
System.out.println(new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393601/5772882) for the good solution.